Access Wireguard (wg0) interface from outside docker container
I want to run a Nuclei scan through a VPN configured inside a docker container. I am using the thrnz/docker-wireguard-pia image, and the container starts correctly. When running the Nuclei scan inside another Docker container, it works correctly through the VPN with the following command: docker run --rm --net=container:vpn projectdiscovery/nuclei:latest -l targets.txt. However, I now want to execute Nuclei locally (outside of Docker), and I want to use the -i option to select the network interface. My goal is to run something like:
nuclei -i wg0 -l targets.txt

The VPN container creates wg0 interface but it is only accessible inside docker. When I execute ip a command I don`t see the wg0 interface. How can I access that interface from outside the Docker container?
Here is the Docker Compose configuration for the VPN:
vpn:
        image: thrnz/docker-wireguard-pia
        container_name: vpn
        volumes:
            # Auth token is stored here
            - pia:/pia
            # If enabled, the forwarded port is dumped to /pia-shared/port.dat for potential use in other containers
            - pia-shared:/pia-shared
            # If the kernel module isn't available, mounting the tun device may be necessary for userspace implementations
            #devices:
            - /dev/net/tun:/dev/net/tun
        cap_add:
            - NET_ADMIN
            # SYS_MODULE might not be needed with a 5.6+ kernel?
            - SYS_MODULE
        environment:
            # The following env vars are required:
            - LOC=spain
            - USER=${PIA_USERNAME}
            - PASS=${PIA_PASSWORD}
            # The rest are optional:
            # - LOCAL_NETWORK=192.168.1.0/24
            #- KEEPALIVE=25
            #- VPNDNS=8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
            #- PORT_FORWARDING=1
        sysctls:
            # The wg-quick script tries to set this when setting up routing, however this requires running the container
            # with the --privileged flag set. Setting it here instead if needed means the container can be run with lower
            # privileges. This only needs setting if strict reverse path filtering (rp_filter=1) is used.
            - net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
            # May as well disable ipv6. Should be blocked anyway.
            - net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
            - net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
            - net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1
        # The container has no recovery logic. Use a healthcheck to catch disconnects.
        healthcheck:
            test: ping -c 1 www.google.com || exit 1
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 10s
            retries: 3
        restart: always


A container cannot inject an interface into the host unless (a) you run it with --net=host (so it shares the host namespace) and (b) run it with additional privileges (--cap-add net_admin should be sufficient).
